# Kubernetes NodePort is not accessible outside. Connection refused

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to learn Kubernetes.

I am trying to do this using Minikube and here is what I did:

1.) Write a simple server using Node

2.) Write a `Dockerfile` for that particular Node server

3.) Create a Kubernetes `deployment`

4.) Create a service (of type ClusterIP)

5.) Create a service (of type NodePort) to expose the container so I can access from outside (browser, curl)

But when I try to connect to the `NodePort` with the format of `<NodePort>:<port>` and `:, it gives an error:

> Failed to connect to 192.168.39.192 port 80: Connection refused

These are the files I created as steps mentioned above (1-5).

**1.) server.js** - Here only I have mentioned `server.js`, relevent `package.json` exists and they work as expected when I run the server locally (without deploying it in Docker), I mention this in case readers might ask whether my server works correctly.

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');

// Constants
const PORT = 8080;
const HOST = '0.0.0.0';

// App
const app = express();
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello world\n');
});

app.listen(PORT, HOST);
console.log(`Running on http://${HOST}:${PORT}`);
```

**2.) Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:10

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

**3.) deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: node-web-app
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: node-web-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        # you can specify any labels you want here
        name: node-web-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: node-web-app
        # image must be the same as you built before (name:tag)
        image: banuka/node-web-app
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
        imagePullPolicy: Never
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
```

**4.) clusterip.yaml**

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  labels:
    # these labels can be anything
    name: node-web-app-clusterip
  name: node-web-app-clusterip
spec:
  selector:
    app: node-web-app
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      # target is the port exposed by your containers (in our example 8080)
      targetPort: 8080
```

**5.) NodePort.yaml**

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  labels:
    name: node-server-nodeport
  name: node-server-nodeport
spec:
  # this will make the service a NodePort service
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: node-app-web
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      # new -> this will be the port used to reach it from outside
      # if not specified, a random port will be used from a specific range (default: 30000-32767)
      nodePort: 32555
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
```

And when I try to curl from outside or use my web browser it gives following error:

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.39.192 port 32555: Connection refused

PS: pods and containers are also working as expected.

Comment: Very first question are you able to run you docker image, before getting that into kubernetes, you should first try to do that. Build the docker image and run to make sure you have correct docker image then try to get that into kubernetes deployment.

Comment: Yes now it is working :) Thank you

Comment: @BhagyaKolithaJayalath , it would be good if you could describe your solution as an answer, so next stack user can see/find it easily

Answer (score 3):

There are several possible reasons for this.
First: Are you using your local IP or the IP where the minikube VM is running? To verify use `minikube ip`.
Second: The `NodePort` service wants to use pods with label `app: node-app-web`, but your pods only have the label `name: node-web-app`
Just to make sure the port that you assume is used, check with `minikube service list` that the requested port was allocated. Check your firewall settings as well.

Comment: thanks, after using minikube IP it's worked.

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem always when I write wrong selectors to NodePort service spec

Answer (score 1):

The Service's selector must match the **Pod's** label.

In your *NodePort.yaml* selector is `app: node-app-web` , while in *deployment.yaml* label is `node-web-app`.